# WPF: How to relayout wrappanel?

Tags: wpf, wrappanel

I have a `WrapPanel` placed in a grid and fill it dynamically with `ToggleButtons`.
The height of the row, where the `wrappanel` is located in, is calculated based on the number of `ToggleButtons` in the `WrapPanel` component.

When I load my screen the items in the `wrappanel` aren't layouted correctly.
However when I resize my form the items are shown correctly.

Is there a method where you can force to relayout the items like it does when you resize your form ?

Below you can see my WPF code:

```
<Grid x:Name="grdScreen">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="rdToolBar" Height="21" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0" Name="btnlegende" Margin="1,1,11,1" Click="btnlegende_Click" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Name="btnlayout" Margin="1" Click="btnlayout_Click" />
        <WrapPanel x:Name="pnlHeader" Grid.Column="2" />
    </Grid>
...
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.UpdateLayout();

Comment: I tried it already.
Even pnlHeader.upateLayout().
It doesn't work.

Comment: Just try putting the Wrap panel code seperately in a usercontrol, i mean not inside the Grid.

Comment: I replaced the grid by a StackPanel and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [InvalidateArrange()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatearrange.aspx) or [InvalidateMeasure()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatemeasure.aspx) to force WPF to redo the appropriate layout phase.